# How to make sure that a command is not interrupted, even if terminal is closed?

Tags: command-line, terminal, background-process, exit

In Linux. Say I want to run a command and it takes too long. I just want to ensure it's done. How?

Answer (score 33):

`nohup`

read the man page for `nohup` usage.

`nohup` is the way it's been done long since before `screen`, `tmux`, etc were invented.

Example:

```
nohup my_long_running_proc &
```

Runs "my_long_running_proc", and any console (stdout/stderr) messages go into a file called "nohup.out" in the directory from which the command was started.

Comment: true. The init process kills all children of a process before killing the process itself, with the exception of processes started with nohup. These processes will then be moved under init.

Comment: I've been using nohup since the days when I connected to shell account via modem, wanted long running command to stay running and complete so I could logout and hangup not incurring phone charges, or having modem disconnect midway. Tried and true, decades of testing.

Answer (score 8):

Use `tmux` or `screen` to provide a persistent session environment for the command to run in.

Using `tmux`, this could be accomplished in the following way:

- Start a new session environment: `tmux new -s my-session-name`
- Run your command: `longrunningcommand`
- Close your terminal window, SSH session or manually detach from `tmux` using `Ctrl+b`, then `d`
- Reconnect to your session using: `tmux attach-session -t my-session-name`

`tmux` can do way more beyond that, but one basic thing which should probably be added: Use `tmux list-sessions` to see all active sessions.

Answer (score 7):

Test it with the command xclock. Open a console, type

```
xclock
```

Close the console. xclock disappears. Now type

```
xclock &
```

xclock still disappears cause it is still a sub-process of your shell. Now type

```
xclock & disown
```

Now xclock is no longer a sub-process of your shell and you can close the console and xclock will keep running.

I documented this here: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Disown

Comment: This doesn't let you check the output and/or exit status of the program - which is a rather important part of the question.

Comment: Well actually the question doesn't say anything about checking output or exit status. True, there are many cases where that is important information, but this may not be one of them.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use screen (man screen)
2. append "&" at the end of the command. It will be launched into background and if You kill the terminal session I think it should complete. Anyway I recommend to always use screen.

Comment: So even if terminal is death it'll still work>

Comment: with screen -> 100%. With the & launch in background I am not 100% sure. You can launch a command with & (like sleep 1000). kill terminal and from another terminal check ps auwx|grep sleep

Comment: You don't need to append `&` if you use screen. Just hit `Ctrl + A` then `Ctrl + D` to leave the `screen` session. And the command you launched is still running.

Comment: If your terminal becomes Death, I suspect you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 4):

When you log out of your shell, any still running chldren are sent a SIGHUP signal.  For your process to continue to run after logout, it needs to trap, ignore or avoid this signal, since the default behaviour is to exit.

The `nohup` command will ignore the signal, and is a common way to do it if the process does not send anything important to `stdout`.

The `screen` command (which is my preference) creates a shell-within-a-shell that can be detatched and reattached, so it avoids the signal being generated at all (or rather, it detatches from the parent so it never gets the signal).

If the process is written by yourself, you can code it to catch the signal and then perform any action, including ignoring it, so that it continues to run after logging out.  Your process could also completely disassociate from its parent process (see `setsid()`) so that, as with `screen`, it does not receive the SIGHUP during logout.

Which method you choose is up to you and which is more appropriate for your situation and use.

Answer (score 2):

With bash 3.2, I found that `disown -h` works best. For example, to prevent `gedit` from closing when the terminal closes, I need to *both* put it in the background and use `disown`. It is easy to do this via a function in ~/.bashrc:

```
ge() { gedit "$@" & disown -h; }  # need double--not single--quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

use tmux:

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

To start it simply type `tmux` and to minimize it press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and then <kbd>d</kbd> to start the same session type `tmux attach`.

Comment: A bit Ubuntu specific instructions - not everyone is using these.

Comment: @peterph user did not mention what distro he/she is using

Comment: ... and that's exactly my point.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the command's `stdout` and `stderr` to a file, save its exit value and then run it in `nohup` or (better) under a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen`:

```
command 1> command.out 2> command.err; echo $? > command.exit
```

To check the progress you can simply `tail -f` the log files. The point of logging into files is that terminal multiplexers have a limited buffers (although one can usually set it to be large enough for most tasks) and they *might* crash, in which case all the output would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I very small but efficient tool that substitute `tmux` and `screen` well is `dtach`, it strips out all those complicated windows management functions but only serve to preserve the job in the back and bring it foreground at any time you like.